# List folder contents, create thumbnails

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure this question has been asked and answered many times but I can't for the life of me find the answer I'm looking for.

Please bear with me, hopefully this will make sense, also I'm an enthusiast coder so please be gentle.

So I run a website for a very small 4x4 club.  We hold get together once a month and get our cars all dirty.  A few hundred photos get taken and are then uploaded to the website.  I have to then manually create the html and thumbnails which can take quite a long time.

So, I'm looking for help and advice to make this task much easier and quicker.  The website is running on IIS and I don't have root access so it's difficult to install anything.

Hopefully there's something out there to help me with this.

Many thanks..

Comment: Consider a Facebook or Flickr group or something. It's certainly possible to create a gallery folks can submit to on your own, but if you're asking this vague a question there's likely to be a steep learning curve to do so.

Comment: (If you're willing to ditch your current site/server, something like Wix, Tumblr, etc. might do the trick too.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks as though you are asking a question that is [**over your head**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328017) (and thus too broad for Stack Overflow). Break your task down into individual steps, [**attempt each step**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), then come back with a specific problem you encountered. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). And you'll want a CMS :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need content management system.

Checkout wordpress.com, which is the most famous and widely used content management system. It is also very easy to get started and does not require any coding knowledge.

**What is a content management system (CMS)?**
A CMS allows you to manage your website via an easy to use portal. No coding is required. No scripting is required. The CMS is essentially a layer on top of all your code. It does the coding for you.

Instead of manually typing out the code to put your pictures, a CMS will let you simply upload the photo, as if it was a normal file. Then you can add any captions, headers etc. Depending on the complexity of the CMS.

This should make your life a lot easier. Check out wordpress.com.